Split User name from one field to two fields in HIVE
I have a field:  Username.
the ouput is lastname,firstname (No extra space after the comma)
Ultimately, I need to script the display to be firstname lastname.
My thought is to split the username on the comma into separate fields then concatenate to the intended order.
What is the ideal way to split based on the comma?  Thanks in advance.
So far, I have only researched for solutions, but nothing has been successful yet.

I was able to cobble this together to meet my needs.
select
username
,split(username, ',')[0] as user_first_name
,split(username, ',')[1] as user_last_name

I was able to cobble this together to meet my needs.
select
username
,split(username, ',')[0] as user_first_name
,split(username, ',')[1] as user_last_name
using: Splitting data into multiple columns in Hive
